# Bootstrap Calender Setup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Helo!

I would like to say thank you in advance for your support.

I am trying to use [this html and css](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar) to make a calender in bootstrap.  I am having a lot of trouble and after following the documentation I end up with a blank page.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WR | Calender</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap2/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="calendar"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/jstimezonedetect/jstz.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar({
        events_source: [
            {
                "id": 293,
                "title": "Event 1",
                "url": "http://example.com",
                "class": "event-important",
                "start": 12039485678000, // Milliseconds
                "end": 1234576967000 // Milliseconds
            }
        ]});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "calendar.js", "calendar.css".

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calendar.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
```

I really recommend you to add every javascript file and CSS file in the header section.

Comment: You my friend are awesome!  Does it matter in what order I include the .js files?